# The colour for hyperlinks in LibreOffice Calc makes them very difficult to see. How to change?

Tags: libreoffice, 22.04, appearance

Having set the system highlight colour (Settings > Appearance):
[image]

I find that LibreOffice Calc shows hyperlinks in this colour, making them very difficult to see:
[image]

How do I change the style of the default hyperlink text in LibreOffice (7.3.3.2) Calc?

I have checked the [LibreOffice online help](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-GB/text/shared/guide/hyperlink_edit.html?&DbPAR=SHARED&System=UNIX) but the steps in the section **Changing the attribute of all hyperlinks** (which seems to be the relevant section) ask you to; ***Right-click the "Internet Link" or "Visited Internet Link" character style, and choose Modify***, I am unable to find either of those character styles.

Comment: did you try the "styles" tab at the top? what does it show?

Comment: I've been all over the Styles menu item and the Styles sidebar, no joy.